# How can I track conversions on third party websites?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, affiliate

We run a number of affiliate schemes, and I would like to track which links from our website produce sales, and which do not. I can persuade our affiliates to include tracking code in their pages for us; what product or method is best suited for this purpose?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any more details, I would say check out Google Analytics. You can set up a different tracking code for each of your affiliate websites so you can separate results on a site-by-site basis.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Just to add to this, we had our affiliates create google analytics profiles that showed us only the traffic we sent them. This meant we could see what our referred users were doing on their sites, including coversions.